# Push Notication Fcm cloud function, Mismatch SenderId error Nodejs

Tags: node.js, push-notification, push

I am using Fcm cloud funtions for push notification,notifications was working fine but suddenly facing issue of Mismatch SenderId don't know what the problem.I am using same server key as the senderID  and team Id and Key Id and device token also fine but facing this issue in nodejs mongodb.any body can resolve this issue ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, i solve this issue by myself.if you facing this issue and everything is fine but still gets the error of Mismatch senderID,then please genrate new server key and save this in  your project json and download plist file and save in the frontend  project then genrate a new build in your device and check you will receive notification successfully.Thanks